# generic way to check null or empty for any type like int, string, double

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying t get this working but somehow its going out of my hand... I want to be able to check null or empty to whatever type i assigned.

EX:

```
int i =0;
string mystring = "";

var reult  = CheckNullOrEmpty(10) // passing int
var result 1  = CheckNullOrEmpty(mystring) // passing string 

 public bool CheckNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
 {
    // check for null or empty for strings
    // check for null i.e. 0 for int 

 }
```

can someone help me with this.. I am trying to understand how generics works for this simple method.

Comment: i think u need to create many method and named it all CheckNullOrEmpty. each method checks different data types

Comment: I think you can't generically check for such a thing as *empty*, since there's no general definition: For a `string` it's an empty string, for an `int` it may be `0`, but for *any type `T`* it may be just anything or not even exist...

Comment: If you want a default value comparison, compare against `default(T)`. That's the best you can do here.

Comment: I dont think that would be the right way as i have seen somewhere on the internet about this.. i cant seems to find this now and hence i asked the question...

Comment: @Doctor, could you please give me an example to use default(T)..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
public static bool CheckNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
{
     if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);

     return value == null || value.Equals(default(T));
}
```

How to use:

```
class Stub { }

bool f1 = CheckNullOrEmpty(""); //true
bool f2 = CheckNullOrEmpty<string>(null); //true
bool f3 = CheckNullOrEmpty(0); //true
bool f4 = CheckNullOrEmpty<Stub>(null);  //true
```

Comment: What if `T` is a reference type <>  `string` and value is `null`?

Comment: Any reason for if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) instead of if (value is string) ?

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: if `value` is `null`, the `value is string` does not work

Answer (score 2):

You can check against `default(T);`

```
 public bool CheckNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
 {
      return value == default(T);
 }
```

For more informations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't cover string.Empty.

Comment: it says Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Comment: You could check `if typeof(T) == typeof(string)` and then test for string.empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default() -

e.g.:

```
if(value != default(T))
```

from MSDN:

> Given a variable t of a parameterized type T, the statement t = null
>   is only valid if T is a reference type and t = 0 will only work for
>   numeric value types but not for structs. The solution is to use the
>   default keyword, which will return null for reference types and zero
>   for numeric value types. For structs, it will return each member of
>   the struct initialized to zero or null depending on whether they are
>   value or reference types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This does not cover string.Empty values

Answer (score 1):

Because your `CheckNullOrEmpty` implementation differs by type, you can't have that check as a  generic function.

If you use `Nullable` value types however, you can use [`GetValueOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
int? i = 0;

var result = i.GetValueOrDefault(10);
```

Then for `string`, just have an extension method:

```
public static string GetValueOrDefault(this string item, string defaultValue = "")
{
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item) ? item : defaultValue;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
string i = null;
string mystring = "";

var result  = i.GetValueOrDefault(mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I've added a couple of re-factorings:

 1. DBNull is not seen as isnullorempty so added the (value as string)
 2. Passing a datatable row[column] that was created dynamically at runtime (like: row["PropertyName"]) will not see this as a string with typeof(T) due to the fact that the column type base is object. So added an extra check for typeof(object) and if not null test that the ToString() is empty value. I haven't tested this fully so may not work for all types of data columns.
```

```
  public static bool CheckNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
  {
        // note: this does not see DBNull as isnullorempty.  
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
            {
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString().Trim());
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(object))
        {
            // note: datatable columns are always seen as object at runtime with generic T regardless of how they are dynamically typed?
            if (value != null) {
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString().Trim());
            }
        }


      return value == null || value.Equals(default(T));
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

if you know T is class, then all class can be null so, you can check like:

```
public bool CheckIsDefault<T>(T value)
where T: class
{
    return value == default(T);
}
```